# Microsoft Teams Apps: Issue using media permissions for tabs

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm trying to develop a tab for Microsoft Teams which needs to access the microphone. According to the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/mobile-camera-image-permissions?view=msteams-client-js-latest

I need to add this property to the manifest.json:

```
"devicePermissions": [ 
    "media",
 ],
```

When i open my tab, i can see this message:

[image]

The problem is I also need to use my application in a different window

[image]

But, when i select that option and have my app running in a different window, i can't see the message to allow that permission and my tab can't use the microphone

I also try to grant that permission before open my app in a different window, but it doesn't work neither.

What could i do in this case?

Comment: Could you please share sample that you are following. As per my knowledge use of microphone is supported on mobiles. We tried a sample in mobile and it was working fine.

Comment: Any updates on the issue?